# Question about Monte Carlo Simulation of 2D lattice Ising Model and Classical Heisenberg Model

Tags: statistical-mechanics, simulations, ising-model

I'm trying run and experiment with Monte Carlo Simulations of 2D lattice Ising Model and Classical Heisenberg Model.

I've made a brief research on both models and I saw that main differences of these two models are:

1. In Ising Model, spins of each vertice may only be $\sigma_i=\{-1, 1\}$ but in Classical Heisenberg Model spins are 3-component unit vectors $\vec{\sigma_i}\in R^3$ and $|\vec{\sigma_i}|=1$.
2. Hamiltonian of Ising Model is $H=\sum_{<i,j>}{J_{i,j}\sigma_i\sigma_j}$ and of Classical Heisenberg Model is $H=\sum_{<i,j>}{J_{i,j}\vec{\sigma_i}\cdot\vec{\sigma_j}}$ where $<i,j>$ represents closest neighbors of spin i.

**Question 1:** Is there any main differences am I missing?

**Question 2:** In Ising Model we can calculate the magnetization of system using $M=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i}{\sigma_i}$ formula. How do we calcualte magnetization of system in Classical Heisenberg Model?

Comment: **1.** No, these are the main differences at the level of the definitions of these models (but they differ considerably at the level of their properties). **2.** It's the same definition (the empirical average of the spins $\vec{\sigma}_i$).

Comment: @YvanVelenik OK, so can we assume that magnetization calculated similar to the Ising model in classical Heisenberg model? In Ising model magnetization is given by $M=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}{\sigma_i}$ so in classical Heisenberg model $M=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}{\vec{\sigma_i}}$?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: @YvanVelenik Alright, thanks for help. If you combine these comments into an answer I can accept it as a correct answer. Your comments were helpful, thanks. By the way, have you ever worked with Ising model and Heisenberg model Monte Carlo simulations?

Comment: I don't think that my answers above deserve more than being comments. But I am glad they helped you. I have used various Monte-Carlo simulation schemes in the past, yes, but as an amateur (usually to prepare illustrations for my papers or my book); my actual research is in mathematical physics.

Comment: @YvanVelenik I have some questions related to Ising Model's Monte Carlo simulation with Metropolis algorithm. It's about the transition probabiltiy calculations, I use a book for a reference to experiment the algorithm but the transition probability calculation done in the algorithm (code) and in the theory given in the book are different and I'm not able to understand why they are different. Could you assist me on this?

Comment: There are infinitely many ways of setting up a reversible Markov chain with the Ising distribution as stationary measure. They may practically differ in efficiency (rejection rate, etc). You should probably ask another question on this issue (with an explicit description of the actual algorithms).

Comment: @YvanVelenik OK, I'll do as you say. Can I can mention you in the question so you get a notification? I've not seen anything related to this in question creation steps.

Comment: If you put a "statistical-mechanics" and/or "Ising-model" tag to your question, then I'll see it (they are among the tags I follow).

Comment: Note also that there is a stackexchange dedicated to [computational science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @YvanVelenik Oh, thanks for info. Didn't know there was another dedicated stackexchange for that. It'll be come in handy surely.

Comment: @YvanVelenik I just posted a question computational science stackexchange, could you check [my question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/42827/monte-carlo-simulation-of-classical-heisenberg-model-doesnt-represent-curie-cur) there to see if you can help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: A couple of comments on your question there (I am not a member of this SE community and cannot comment there): **1.** do not use Boltzmann's constant (due to its tiny size, it sets a crazy energy scale; there is a phase transition when the relevant parameter $\beta=1/(k_BT)$ is of the order of $1$ (in the Ising model, $\beta_c \approx 0.44$ with the usual setting). **2.** There is no ordered phase at low temperature in the 2d Heisenberg model (Mermin-Wagner theorem).

Comment: @YvanVelenik thanks for checking out my question. I thought of the same thing you mentioned on your 1st statement, so I also tried setting $k_B=1$ but it didn't change the results, only scaled them a bit more. I couldn't understand your 2nd statement, I'm not familiar with the theorem but I suppose I should increase the temperature range, if so I also tried increasing temperature range 0-100 but I think I might try 0-600 etc. right?

Comment: My second comment is about the fact that there is no phase transition in the two-dimensional Heisenberg model. If I find time, I'll try to have a look at your code, but I cannot promise anything...